# Automate Eclipse build configurations for referenced projects

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration

I have 3 C projects (prj_1, prj_2 and prj_3) in my workspace. prj_3 is referenced by prj_2 and prj_2 is referenced by prj_1.

For each project I have 4 build configurations as x86_win_debug, x86_win_release, x86_linux_debug and x86_linux_release.

The problem arises when I want to change the build configuration of prj_1 from one to another. I have to change the build configuration of the sub-projects (referenced projects) one by one manually. Is there any way to automate this process without using my own makefile? i.e. I change the build configuration of prj_1 to x86_win_debug and I want all the sub-projects be compiled with x86_win_debug configuration even if their last configurations are different then x86_win_debug. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the "Project References" settings in the "Paths and Symbols" page of your project's properties. See also [the related Eclipse help entry](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_referenced_configs.htm).

I have just tested this by deleting the associated build folder from the referenced project and building the dependent project.